# PATH variable in .zshenv or .zshrc

Tags: path, zsh

My setup is zsh 5.0.5 in arch linux

I have set the PATH variable as below in .zshenv

```
typeset -U path
path=(~/bin $path)
DW=$HOME/Downloads
```

but it didn't work. print $PATH shows only

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

.zshenv was read, because I could see DW variable is set. Only PATH variable isn't set. And what I don't understand is, after rename the .zshenv to .zshrc, PATH variable just works as intended.

Need any special treatment setting environment variables in .zshenv?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I just encountered this problem myself, and the real answer is that Zsh on Arch sources `/etc/profile` – which overwrites and exports `PATH` – **after** having sourced `~/.zshenv`.

See: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Zsh#Configuration_files

Comment: Wow. Same on MacOSX, btw. Very unexpected behaviour - at least for me.

Comment: I just had the same problem on _Arch Linux_. The culprit is `/etc/zsh/zprofile` file, which says `emulate sh -c 'source /etc/profile'`. And the reason I found it was that my `SublimeLinter` couldn't correctly read `PERL5LIB`!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that when you have macos or some linux distros there is a [canonical solution to the problem](http://www.softec.lu/site/DevelopersCorner/MasteringThePathHelper) which involves `/etc/paths` or `/etc/paths.d`. You should be letting `/usr/libexec/path_helper` construct your path for you using configuration files.

This immediately solved the problem in all places for me.

Comment: How do I do this?

Answer (score -1):

I've got the same problem. The cause was my .zshrc (fresh install of oh-my-zsh) override PATH (ignoring existing value):

```
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/core_perl"
```

To fix, I comment the line.