# Is there anything in Zsh like .bash_profile?

Tags: bash, zsh

Everytime I open the terminal, I have to source `.bash_profile` to enable the `$JAVA_HOME` or other variables.

Answer (score 251, accepted):

Yes, it's called `~/.zshenv`.

Here's how I have `$JAVA_HOME` set in `~/.zshenv`:

```
export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home)"
```

Keep in mind, however, that zsh is **not** bash, so just 'cause you have to source your `.bash_profile` every time you open a terminal does *not* mean that you have to do that with zsh.  With zsh, I only have to re-source my `~/.zshenv` *when I make changes to it*, and then *only for terminals which are already open*: new terminals should have already sourced my new and improved `~/.zshenv`.

**NOTE**

I often find it helpful, when trying to determine which of my zsh startup files I should place things in to consult [zsh startup files](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_3.html).

A newer version of the documentation for startup files can be found [here](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Files.html).

Comment: Actually, `.zprofile` is closer in meaning to `.bash_profile`, in that both are only sourced by their respective shells for login shells. `.zshenv` is executed for *all* instances of `zsh`, whether or not they are login shells.

Comment: @chepner `.zshenv` is where all environment variables should be defined.  See [here](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_3.html)

Comment: Agreed; `.bash_profile` has to do for `bash` what `.zshenv` and `.zprofile/.zlogin` together do for `zsh`. That link provides good information on what should go where.

Comment: @Alexej Problem with defining `PATH` in `.zshenv` is that it could later be overridden, say by `/etc/profile`; see [PATH variable in .zshenv or .zshrc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34244862/183120).

Comment: @AlexejMagura I used to think that. `.zshenv` is sourced for *all* shells, though, including non-interactive shells. I would stick with `.zprofile` unless you have a *very* good reason for affecting other scripts.

Comment: @ennth Both will be sourced for interactive login shells; use `.zprofile` for things that should be inherited by non-`zsh` processes (like `PATH` or program-specific environment variables); use `.zshrc` for things specific to `zsh` itself, like `PS1` (which does *not* need to be exported).

Comment: @chepner According to the documentation for Zsh, `.zprofile`/`.zlogin` should not affect the shell environment at all.

Comment: I disagree with that comment. `.zshenv` is sourced for *any* shell (including non-login interactive shells and non-interactive shells), which means it would be used far more often than is necessary for configuring your environment variables. I restrict that file to `zsh`-specific things, like `zstyle` commands: things that will not be *inherited* from a parent process.

Comment: @chepner All I'm saying is that the documentation (and by extension the developers) don't agree with putting environmental settings in `.zprofile`/`.zlogin`.

Comment: It's not in the current man page, though. Note that your link was last updated in 1995.

Comment: @chepner Ah, fair enough.

Comment: https://ss64.com/mac/syntax-profile.html

Answer (score 80):

I know this is an old question, but I recently upgraded MacOs to Catalina which changed the default shell from bash to zsh.

I ended up doing this:

```
 echo source ~/.bash_profile > ~/.zshenv && source ~/.zshenv
```

To have zsh source my original .bash_profile.

Comment: Use the command like this to ensure that the file is created in the users home directory:
`echo source ~/.bash_profile > ~/.zshenv`

Comment: Is the use of `echo` important here? What does that do?

Comment: @QASam, echo is a must here,   `X > Y` only pass what X outputted. Without echo, nothing is outputted.

Comment: This works to find my aliases but I still need to source to get the terminal to lad the correct prompt/colors for some reason.

Comment: This worked fine for me.

Answer (score 22):

Recently, with the upgrade to macOS Catalina, the default shell changed to zsh, which uses `~/.zshrc` as the resource file.

We usually had `~/.bash_profile` inside user home directory the solution is to simply

1. Open `~/.bash_profile` by running `vim ~/.bash_profile`
2. Open `~/.zshrc` by running `vim ~/.zshrc`
3. Copy the content of `~/.bash_profile` into `~/.zshrc`

Open a new terminal window and run your previous aliases/scripts, which should work flawlessly.

Comment: You could also add `source ~/.bash_profile` at the end of the ~/.zshrc.

Comment: note that all aliases should also be added at the bottom of `~/.zshrc`.

Answer (score 15):

There are five separate profile scripts that get executed (in the order given below) when we launch a zsh shell or close it out.

`(1) .zshenv` --> This is always sourced first but can be overridden by other

`(2).zprofile` --> This is equivalent for users coming from ksh experience

`(3).zshrc`  --> This is for all of the interactive customizations of zsh

`(4).zlogin`  --> This executes after first three are done

`(5).zlogout` --> This is executed when we logout of the zsh shell
it would be advisable to put your stuff in .zshenv or in .zshrc

It is not **mandatory** to have any one of these files. But if it is there, it will be sourced from and executed in the above order.

Answer (score 12):

Other simple alternative to continue using your .bash_profile is add this file to your .zshrc file:

1. Open your .zhsrc file > vim ~/.zshrc
2. Add this line to your .zshrc file > source ~/.bash_profile

with this simple solution you can continue adding your .bash_prifile if you like zhs.

[Adding .bash_profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6ppr.png)

Comment: could there be some differences between bash and zsh that caused bash_profile not to start properly? see http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq02.html#l14

Answer (score 6):

In Mac Catalina onwards osx versions, the terminal uses zsh. There is a system-wide profile `/etc/zprofile`.

Output example for `cat /etc/zprofile`:

```
# System-wide profile for interactive zsh(1) login shells.

# Setup user specific overrides for this in ~/.zprofile. See zshbuiltins(1)
# and zshoptions(1) for more details.

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi
```

it says , if you want to override then create `~/.zprofile`.

```
touch ~/.zprofile.
```

Answer (score 2):

update: macOS Monterey 12.4

yes - for Zsh, it is the file: `.zshrc`
add there your parameter.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32206746)

Answer (score 0):

In Mac Catalina, terminal uses zsh. Instead of having .bash_profile, good to have .zshenv and write your script there.

When you open terminal next every time, scripts inside .zshenv gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this issue and I followed Zack and Luke Schoen's answer, but my `$PATH` didn't look the same as what I had in **bash**.

This post explains what the different config files do:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71253/what-should-shouldnt-go-in-zshenv-zshrc-zlogin-zprofile-zlogout

I found that splitting my `.bash_profile` path exports into `.zprofile` and my aliases into `.zshrc` worked best for what I wanted.

I found why Zack and Luke Schoen's answer didn't work for me:

The path exports that I listed in `.zshenv` were executed first and `/usr/libexec/path_helper` was executed afterwards,
which prepended the paths listed in `/etc/paths`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the profile file under `/etc/zprofile` location. This will be for `zsh`

Answer (score -1):

yes -->
.zshrc   is similar to .bash_profile in MAC Ventura

Comment: This has already been mentioned in other answers.