# macOS Catalina: bash → zsh? Where to add new path variables

Tags: path, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Ever since the latest macOS update, I've been using zsh as the default shell. However, all my PATH variables are set up in `~/.bash_profile`.

`~/.zprofile` and `~/.zshenv` doesn't exist, and `~/.zshrc` has no path variables

My question is: where should I actually put my path variables in the future?
Everything seems to work fine (GO Path, Python, Node paths - none of them are in the zsh profile though..)

Comment: You simply *create* `.zprofile`. Just like `bash`, `zsh` only sources the standard files if they exist.

Comment: So if I create `.zprofile` with a different path than the one in `bash_profile` - does `.zprofile` override the `bash_profile` one?

Comment: `zsh` isn't using `bash_profile` *at all*, unless you are sourcing it explicitly (which you shouldn't). It sources `/etc/zprofile` first, which uses `path_helper` to construct an initial `PATH` the same way `/etc/profile` (which was used by `bash`) does.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there anything in Zsh like .bash\_profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23090390/is-there-anything-in-zsh-like-bash-profile)